# Add login account to access "WSS_Content"

Tags: permissions, sql-server

I need to run the [SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard (2.8)](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) on SP 2010. It tries to read the database "WSS_Content" using my login account but keeps blowing up with this error when it tries to do the `Binding to site - please wait`:

```
 Cannot open database "WSS_Content" requested by the login. The login failed.
 Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\mylogin_id'.
```

I'm admin on the box but not sure if I need to add myself to other groups on the box as well. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't have proper permissions on the SQL side. Add your login as the SQL administrator or grant the permission directly on the databsae WSS_Content, for example db_owner role.

UPDATE:
This should help You:
[Link](http://support.gearhost.com/KB/a453/adding-users-to-mssql-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx) but You should select "Windows authentication" and YOu should search for Your login name MYDOMAIN\mylogin_id

Comment: Thanks, zavaz. I think you're right; this article also talks about the same thing: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/58942bbd-de82-4bd2-a583-3323dd20483d/ Now I need to contact our DBAs and ask them to fix this.

Comment: If this is a standalone installation (not a farm), where SharePoint created the database itself and we've never logged into it directly ourselves, will we be able to connect and add/remove users? Or do we need a farm installation to have that level of control on the database? Thanks.

Comment: I think You can instal SQL Management Studio Express and connect to the database using account under which SharePoint was installed.

Comment: Thanks, zavaz. How do you find out which account SharePoint was installed under? On Central Admin > Default Database Server, it's blank for the Database Username and Password, meaning it's using Windows authentication instead.

Comment: That's correct. The best way is to log in to windows as the user ude who YOu instaleld SharePont and then rum SQL management studio to connect to the DB

Comment: Thanks, zavaz. Our DBA worked on the SQL Express on the server and got us access. I went in and added the various roles and now am able to run the utility.

Comment: Better to start the configuration wizard with 'Run-as other user' and use the SharePoint Admin/Install account.